# Algebra and brackets opening

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I'm trying to clarify, how to open brackets.
Simple example:

$$2a - {4 - [3b -(5a -7 + b)] + 2} = 2a - {4 - 3b +5a +7 - b + 2}$$
As you can see, need to change sign. Opened $()$ changed $-$ to $+$ and vice versa. Any good explanation? Proof, articles ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using more steps. e.g. $2a-4-[3b-(5a-7+b)]+2 = 2a-4-[3b+(-5a+7-b)]+2=\dots$

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in your calculations
\begin{align}-(5a-7+b)&=-5a+7-b\\[0.2cm]-[3b-(5a-7+b)]&=-[3b-5a+7-b]=-3b+5a-7+b\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change the sign when you have two minuses, since:

$-(-a) = +a$

If you have a plus and a minus, then the minus overrules:

$-(+a) = -a$

$+(-a) = -a$

Answer (score 0):

$$2a - 4 - [3b -(5a -7 + b)] + 2 =2a - 4 - 1\cdot[3b -1\cdot(5a -7 + b)] + 2.$$

Now just multiply out as usual.  "Changing signs" isn't a calculation; just remember in such cases that every '$-$' is an abbreviation of '$-1\cdot$'.

If there was a "changing sign rule" we would obtain
$$-(-5)^2=+5^2.$$